# Transaction error pay u money

Tags: payment-gateway

> SORRY! We were unable to process your payment
>   Checksum Failed

test payment script provided by payumoney
web integration
not working 
json 
product info passed still says transaction error

```
<?php
  // Merchant key here as provided by Payu
  $MERCHANT_KEY = "JBZaLc";

  // Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
  $SALT = "GQs7yium";

  // End point - change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode
  $PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";

  $action = '';

  $posted = array();

  if(!empty($_POST)) {
      //print_r($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {    

      $posted[$key] = $value; 

    }
  }

  $formError = 0;

  if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
    // Generate random transaction id
    $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);

  } else {

    $txnid = $posted['txnid'];
  }

  $hash = '';
  // Hash Sequence
  $hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";

  if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {

    if(

      empty($posted['key'])

      || empty($posted['txnid'])

      || empty($posted['amount'])

      || empty($posted['firstname'])

      || empty($posted['email'])

      || empty($posted['phone'])

      || empty($posted['productinfo'])

      || empty($posted['surl'])

      || empty($posted['furl'])

      || empty($posted['service_provider'])

      ) {

      $formError = 1;

  } else {
      //$posted['productinfo'] = json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));

    $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);

    $hash_string = '';  

    foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {

      $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';

      $hash_string .= '|';

    }


    $hash_string .= $SALT;


    $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));

    $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';

  }

} elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) {

  $hash = $posted['hash'];

  $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}

?>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';

  function submitPayuForm() {

    if(hash == '') {

      return;
    }

    var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;

    payuForm.submit();

  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="submitPayuForm()">

  <h2>PayU Form</h2>

  <br/>

  <?php if($formError) { ?>

  <span style="color:red">Please fill all mandatory fields.</span>

  <br/>

  <br/>

  <?php } ?>

  <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">

    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" />

    <table>

      <tr>

        <td><b>Mandatory Parameters</b></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Amount: </td>

        <td><input name="amount" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['amount'])) ? '' : $posted['amount'] ?>" /></td>

        <td>First Name: </td>

        <td><input name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['firstname'])) ? '' : $posted['firstname']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Email: </td>

        <td><input name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['email'])) ? '' : $posted['email']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>Phone: </td>

        <td><input name="phone" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['phone'])) ? '' : $posted['phone']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Product Info: </td>


        <?php

        $arr = json_encode(array('name'=>'abc','description'=>'abcd','value'=>'500','isRequired'=>'true','settlementEvent'=>'EmailConfirmation'));

        ?>







        <td colspan="3"><textarea name="productinfo"><?php echo (empty($arr)) ? '' : $arr ?></textarea></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Success URI: </td>

        <td colspan="3"><input name="surl" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['surl'])) ? '' : $posted['surl'] ?>" size="64" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Failure URI: </td>

        <td colspan="3"><input name="furl" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['furl'])) ? '' : $posted['furl'] ?>" size="64" /></td>

      </tr>


      <tr>

        <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td><b>Optional Parameters</b></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Last Name: </td>

        <td><input name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['lastname'])) ? '' : $posted['lastname']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>Cancel URI: </td>

        <td><input name="curl" value="" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Address1: </td>

        <td><input name="address1" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['address1'])) ? '' : $posted['address1']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>Address2: </td>

        <td><input name="address2" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['address2'])) ? '' : $posted['address2']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>City: </td>

        <td><input name="city" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['city'])) ? '' : $posted['city']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>State: </td>

        <td><input name="state" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['state'])) ? '' : $posted['state']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Country: </td>

        <td><input name="country" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['country'])) ? '' : $posted['country']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>Zipcode: </td>

        <td><input name="zipcode" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['zipcode'])) ? '' : $posted['zipcode']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>UDF1: </td>

        <td><input name="udf1" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf1'])) ? '' : $posted['udf1']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>UDF2: </td>

        <td><input name="udf2" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf2'])) ? '' : $posted['udf2']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>UDF3: </td>

        <td><input name="udf3" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf3'])) ? '' : $posted['udf3']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>UDF4: </td>

        <td><input name="udf4" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf4'])) ? '' : $posted['udf4']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>UDF5: </td>

        <td><input name="udf5" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf5'])) ? '' : $posted['udf5']; ?>" /></td>

        <td>PG: </td>

        <td><input name="pg" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['pg'])) ? '' : $posted['pg']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <?php if(!$hash) { ?>

        <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

        <?php } ?>

      </tr>

    </table>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this . hope key and slat value is not valid . to get a true value .

1. you can find your test key and salt at : Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Merchant Key - Salt.

Comment: I have same issue and my key and salf also correct, can you please tell me other possibility to face same error.