# How do I get the pay u key and salt

Tags: php, payumoney

I am getting a message

> SORRY! We were unable to process your payment Checksum Failed

I have followed their document for the key and salt. The value is as follows.

```
$merchant_key='JBZaLc';
$merchant_salt='GQs7yium';
```

I went through the following links:

- [Transaction error pay u money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645696/transaction-error-pay-u-money)
- ['sorry some error occurred' while integrating PayUMoney payment gateway in Test mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773892/sorry-some-error-occurred-while-integrating-payumoney-payment-gateway-in-test)

According to the above links the key and the salt has been changed. How do I get the key and salt value for testing payu account.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it only for testing purpose then call payu customer care they will provide you key and salt. It may valid maximum for 24 hrs.

Note:- If you don't have a payu account then first create it.

Comment: Yes, first they confirm your account details like registered mobile number then activate test key and salt for that account.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Merchant account in PayU website for SANDBOX.

Under Profile you will get your Merchant ID

Under DASHBOARD you will get Merchnat KEY and SALT Key.

Also Test Card details are available which can be used for testing.